# How do I override related_name in inherited/child objects?

Tags: python, django, orm

Given the following models:

```
class Module(models.Model):
    pass
class Content(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, related_name='contents')

class Blog(Module):
    pass
class Post(Content):
    pass
```

I would like to be able to get all the "post" objects owned by blog doing something like:

```
b = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)
b.posts.all()
```

However, I haven't figured out a good way of doing this. I can't use `b.contents.all()` as I need `Post` instances and not `Content` instances. I won't ever have a root content object, every content object is going to be subclassed, but I can't use abstract classes as I want a central table with all my content in it and then there will be content_blog etc tables for all the unique inherited pieces of content.

I also tried doing this

```
class Content(models.Model):
    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, related_name='%(class)')
```

but that failed miserably as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way might add a method to Blog model to return a Post queryset, like this:

```
class Blog(Module):
    def _get_posts(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(module=self)
    posts = property(_get_posts)
```

The problem is you have to add method for every sub-model. The [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name) seems only works for abstract base class.

Comment: Not accepting yet as I'm really hoping to see a workaround. But this looks like the most promising, though simple, answer. An issue with this is it only works for Blog (or whatever its hardcoded for). A Post might belong to both a Blog and a Forum etc.

Comment: This will not work when querying like related_name does, though.

Answer (score 0):

This solution comes to my mind:

```
# ...

class Blog(Module):
    @property
    def posts(self):
        return self.contents

class Post(Content):
    pass
```

This way, doing `blog.posts` is the same as doing `blog.contents`:

```
>>> blog = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> blog.posts.all()
# [ ... ]
```

Comment: That would work except that doesn't return Post objects. It will return Content objects which is my whole problem.